# Viscosity partial differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, numerical-methods, partial-differential-equations

We consider the 1D equation 
$$u_t + u u_x -\nu u_{xx}=1+ x (t,x) \in [0,+\infty] \times [0,1].$$

i read that

If $\nu >0.01$ the system behaves like a real second order system  in space and we shall treat it like that. If \nu gets much smaller than that the system becomes a singularity perturped first order system (really one dimensional Euler) and develops boundary layers that require special attention.

I don't understand what this paragraphe means. Can any one help me and explein me please.

Merci d’avance pour votre aide.
Bien cordialement

Comment: Can you give a reference to the test you're reading?. I also think there is a typo on the right hand side.